# Cannot get TypeScript 1.5 working on my VS 2013

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2013

I am currently trying on Angular2 + TypeScript 1.5 with the demo project available on Github, but could not get TypeScript1.5 working on my VS 2013. As far as I searched, I have exactly the same issue as this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ngconf2015demo/issues/19
Anyone's help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `PATH` environment variable. 
It might contain paths to both v1.4 and v1.5 which causes the conflict and hence the problem.

It seems that Typescript installer doesn't remove references to previous version from PATH variable.

Comment: Where can I locate/ change this "PATH variable" you speak of.